# Black background on some pages when building to iOS with Cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am having a issue, on one of my app pages (for iPhone 4S it's in all the pages) I got a black screen behind my content, when I do the overscroll at top and bottom (for iPhone 4S it's in the middle of the divs too) that I can't see where its defined, I checked with GapDebug to check if it's CSS but it's not.

I am using Cordova 6.3.1.

I tried:

The Status Bar Style Light on XCode,

```
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />

<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />

<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#c0c0c0" />
```

but nothing seems to change...

[This is the default and correct page on iPhone 5+, the overscroll (bounce) is correct too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8dXm.png)

[On another page on iPhone 5+ when I overscroll it gets this black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS4ix.png)

[On iPhone 4S it gets the black screen even on the home page] (i.imgur.com/HGd0JjN.png)

[And on the overscroll (bounce) too] (i.imgur.com/RexnlZA.png)

The thing is, on iPhone 5+ the black background on overscroll (bounce) is just in one of my pages, the others are ok, normal gray (i.imgur.com/F29Rl0L.png)

PS: Sorry I can't put more than 2 links on my post because my reputation is lower than 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for any class that would be defining the black color as background,  but actually it was this:

```
.app-content {
     background-color:#FFF;
}
```